# JavaScript replace empty comma with zero

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the code I'm using to try to replace empty commas with zero:

```
let str = '<C><P /><Z><S><S P=",,0.3,0.2,,,," L="195" X="256" H="32" Y="306" T="0" /><S P=",,0.3,0.2,,,," L="146" X="587" H="87" Y="257" T="0" /><S P=",,0.3,0.2,,,," L="50" X="333" H="45" Y="82" T="0" /></S><D /><O /></Z></C>';
let repl = str.replace(/,,/g, ",0,");
```

The result is:

```
<C><P /><Z><S><S P=",0,0.3,0.2,0,,0," L="195" X="256" H="32" Y="306" T="0" /><S P=",0,0.3,0.2,0,,0," L="146" X="587" H="87" Y="257" T="0" /><S P=",0,0.3,0.2,0,,0," L="50" X="333" H="45" Y="82" T="0" /></S><D /><O /></Z></C>
```

I expected something like:
`<... P="0,0,0.3,0.2,0,0,0,0" .../>`

How to do it?

Comment: You are replacing two comma with a zero with comma before and after it. That's what you got there. Can you explain why did you expect something else?

Comment: var repl = str.replace(',,', '0,'); this ??

Comment: Add replace ", to "0, And ," to ,0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
repl = repl.replace(/P=",/g, 'P="0,')
repl = repl.replace(/,"/g, ',0"')
```

Answer (score 1):

Although accepted answer does the job, following is a bit generic than that.

```
let str = '<C><P /><Z><S><S P=",,0.3,0.2,,,," L="195" X="256" H="32" Y="306" T="0" /><S P=",,0.3,0.2,,,," L="146" X="587" H="87" Y="257" T="0" /><S P=",,0.3,0.2,,,," L="50" X="333" H="45" Y="82" T="0" /></S><D /><O /></Z></C>';
```

let str =  str.replace(/,+/g, ',').replace(/",|,"/g,'"')

**Explanation:**

1. Replace one or more occurrences of comma with comma

   str.replace(/**,+**/g, '**,**')
2. Now there will not be any duplicates but words within quites will have trailing commas which can be removed using following

str.replace(/**",**|**,"**/g,'"')

**Demo:**

```js
 let str = '<C><P /><Z><S><S P=",,0.3,0.2,,,," L="195" X="256" H="32" Y="306" T="0" /><S P=",,0.3,0.2,,,," L="146" X="587" H="87" Y="257" T="0" /><S P=",,0.3,0.2,,,," L="50" X="333" H="45" Y="82" T="0" /></S><D /><O /></Z></C>';

 let output =  str.replace(/,+/g, ',').replace(/",|,"/g,'"')
 
 console.log("input:", str);
 console.log("output:",output);
```